# Laravel 5.1 nested controller class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The Laravel documentation clearly describes how to change your routes if you nest your controllers in folders. It seems REALLY simple, and yet I'm still getting an error. Here's the error:

> "Class App\Http\Controllers\Input\InputController does not exist"

^That path looks 100% correct to me. What gives?

File Structure:
-Controllers
--Auth
--Input
---InputController.php

Routes:

```
Route::get('input', 'Input\InputController@getInput');
```

InputController:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class InputController extends Controller
{
    public function getInput()
    {
        return response()->view('1_input.input_form');
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change Controller namespace from

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers
```

to

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Input
```

Comment: Thanks! In addition, I also added the line "use App\Http\Controllers\Controller"

Answer (score 1):

1. **namespace** needs to be changed to the directory your controller is in '*App\Http\Input*'
2. You need to pull in Controller with use *App\Http\Controllers\Contoller* so that you can extend it.

   ```
   <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Input;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;  // need Controller to extend  

    use Illuminate\Http\Response;

    class InputController extends Controller
    {
        public function getInput()
        {
          return response()->view('1_input.input_form');
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you should try running a couple commands in your base dir from your terminal (shell/prompt):

```
composer dump-autoload
```

or if you don't have composer set as executable:

```
php composer dump-autoload
```

and then:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

This way your laravel would prepare everything again "from scratch" and should be able to find the missing controller class.

Basically laravel generates some additional files to boot up faster. If you define a new class it doesn't get included into that "compiled" file. This way your class should be "introduced" to the framework.